# Android onCreate method is called again after for a while

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, oncreate, android-memory, onsaveinstancestate

After sometime (on background or front), activity oncreate method triggered again and again. No coming new intent, no refreshing the screen.

Previously I suspected on low memory.I thought that, Android operating system decides to close my application because of poor memory. So  I wrote codes that loging memory size on "onSaveInstanceState" method. Because of every closing time, this method must be called.

After I read this log, this is not the memory situation. More than 1 gB available ram. So this issue is not related to memory situation.

So this is the question?

"Why and when is onCreate called after activity first open?

Answer (score 1):

`onCreate()` is called only once, when an `Activity` is instantiated (created). If you are seeing this method called again, then your `Activity` (or the entire OS process hosting your app) has been killed and then later restarted.

Comment: Android will kill off background OS processes after about 30 minutes if the user has not interacted with them. Android assumes that the process isn't needed if the user has not interacted with it recently. Some manufacturers have customized this with more aggressive process killing behaviour. It should not happen if your app is in the foreground, although if your phone is sleeping for a long time, Android may decide that your OS process isn't necessary either. Running processes consume energy as well as memory and battery life is a high priority for mobile devices.

Comment: Your app needs to function correctly in this environment, so you need to make sure that it works even if it is killed off and restarted.